# Math extrema problem

Tags: optimization

I have a math extremum problem,  but I am unable to solve it.

"Car gasoline use per hour is: $w = 6 - 0.15v + 0.0025v^2$.  At what speed does the car have to travel,  so that it would be cheapest. "

I used derivative to find a global minimum and got $30$km/h,  but my textbook says the correct answer is $49$km/h.

Can anyone help?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you sure the velocity isn't measured in mi/h?

Comment: Yes,  i am located in Europe.

Comment: I guess @Cako is right. The confusion comes from mph and km/h. $49 km/h = 30.4471884 mph$

Answer (score 0):

Your are right

$$w=6+\frac{v^2-60v}{400}=6+\frac{(v-30)^2-900}{400}\ge 6-\frac94$$, the minimum value occurs if $v=30$